# Kill all unnamed sessions

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, tmux

Is there a command/plugging that closes (kill-session) all sessions you haven't explicitly named?

I need this because I have tmux configured to auto-start on bashrc, and this creates a lot of empty sessions when I forget to terminate them or when some tool (vscode) runs a command in the terminal.

So if this is a thing I could just name all the important sessions and autoclose the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming only sessions you haven't named are left as just numbers, you could do something like:

```
tmux ls -F'#{session_name}'|egrep '^[0-9]+$'|xargs -I% tmux kill-session -t "=%"
```

The other thing you could look at perhaps is using the `destroy-unattached` option. You could set it to `on` globally and then set it to `off` for each session when you rename it (perhaps by changing the rename key binding).